# Google Play Game Services createAutoMatchCriteria MIN_OPPONENTS > 1

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm fiddling with the GPGS Android API for the first time and am having some problems getting auto match to work as I'd expect.  I've been using the ButtonClicker sample, which seems to work great as is - when choosing a "Quick game" the waiting room appears and I can connect two players and all of the callbacks are firing as expected.

If I make one change so that createAutoMatchCriteria is called with min_opponents = 2, max_opponents = 2 instead of 1, the waiting room launches and shows placeholders for 2 opponents, however I cannot get any players to connect - onPeerJoined is never called and the two devices just continue to wait as if neither knows the other is available.

Is there something more that needs to happen to enable a 3 player game?  I'm not sure this sample would support actual game play of more than 2 players, but it seems the waiting room piece should attempt to build a room with 3 participants.  Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the [Quick Game Option](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer) guide in the GPGS docs. The code sample Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0); can be tweaked to include up to 3 players as the guide states by changing the first parameter to 3.

Comment: That's what I did, however when I set it to anything larger than 1 I can no longer get any peer connections for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/9

The callbacks fire when the minimum is met, but not one at a time as players are being added.

As a workaround, I tried I saving the Room object that is returned in onRoomCreated and polling to see if the participants in that room change as players are added, but it does not update. Anybody know a way to work around this issue and figure out when players are added one at a time?